# Collision/Rigid body objects not moving an inch

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, collision

I'm trying to make arrows fall onto a table, in order to dispose of them on the table randomly. So I enable collision/rigid body on the table, passive mode, and add collision/rigid body on an arrow, active mode. But when I hit alt+a, nothing's happening, and the arrow won't move an inch. I don't remember having to use anything more to get it to work, but surely I'm doing something wrong ? What I am missing please ? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Scale problem. Since I also used Blender for 3d printing (with scale unit configured at 0.01), all my 3d objects use this scale, and it seems to affect rigid body behavior. I was able to get around the issue switching back to 1 scale unit. It's still not working properly but it's sufficient as for now.

Comment: FYI, unable to reproduce the problem here, with a simple setting and the same unit at 0.01

Comment: Ah, that's because I didn't explain properly. I _usually_ use 0.01 unit scale and my startup script is setup with it , but since this project was different, I changed it along the way as I was modeling. That was not a good idea since I think I messed up some things (for example, I need now to switch to 10 scale unit in order to see the grid in the scene). Long story short : it's a setup issue on my end, and until I figure what I'm doing wrong, I don't think anyone could help me. At this point, only sharing the blend could help me I suppose. Anyway, thank you a lot for trying.

Answer (score 1):

An old question but as it's the top search result...

There may be some Passive items stopping the Sim, remove items that won't interact with anything important from the Rigid Body.

I'd added nearly everything as Passive with its default Convex Hull, which was excessive in my simple case of dropping rocks into a pile.

Using 2.8 and got this issue.

Comment: 3.0 here and ran into the issue as well. Turns out however, that in my case I just had to start playback from frame 1 once. That may sound obvious to many, but it wasn't for me, and took me a while to figure out.